# Composition in thread unxpected result

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have 2 class. 1 network and 1 device. Device is main class contain thread run. Application is to get Network signal. I initiliaze Network class handle inside method open in Device class. then, call CSQ method inside Run method. But, it didn't call CSQ method. Nothing print out. It should be start +CSQ

```
import serial
import time
import threading
import re
from serial import SerialException

class Network:
    def __init__(self, handle):
        self.handle = handle

    def CSQ(self):
       while True:
           self.handle.write('AT+CSQ')

           time.sleep(1)

class Device(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, port, baudrate):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.port = port
        self.baudrate = baudrate

    def open(self):
        try:
            self.handle = serial.Serial(self.port, self.baudrate)
            self.network = Network(self.handle)

            return True
        except SerialException as e:
            error = re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", str(e))
            self.__error = error

            if error[1] == 'Access is denied.':
                return True
            elif error[1] == 'Port is already open.':
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def buffer(self):
        while True:    
            if self.open():
                buffer = self.handle.readline()

                if buffer == b'AT+CGMI\r\r\n':
                    data = []

                    while True:
                        buffers = self.handle.readline()

                        data.append(buffers)

                        if buffers == b'OK\r\n':
                            print(data[0])
                            break
                        elif buffers == b'ERROR\r\n':
                            break

                print(buffer)

                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print('Device is not connecting')

    def write(self, command):
        if self.open():
            self.handle.write(command.encode('UTF-8') + b'\r')

    def error(self):
        return self.__error

    def run(self):
        self.buffer()
        self.network.CSQ()



device = Device('COM12', 9600)

device.open()

device.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `buffer()` method never returns, so `network.CSQ()` is never executed. You need to review the logic of this.

Comment: `buffer()` method only for real time to read buffer. It indepedent thread nothing involve to other method. u can try to after `device.start()` add `for x in range(1000): device.write('AT+CSQ') time.sleep(1)`. it print out buffer. but i need composition ways.

Comment: But the `network.CSQ()` is called **after**  `buffer()` in the `run()`, but `buffer()` never ends, so there will be no **after** :).
The buffer is printed inside `buffer()` method, which is has the infinite loop, yes, its executed.

Comment: method `run` is not to create thread? as i know i just include how many function to be thread. and later use start method to start all method as thread.

Comment: The method `run()` is executed by `start()` inside the thread, it cannot be "splited" to create a thread for each call inside it. If you want to do it parallel  you need two different threads with different `run()` methods.

Comment: `t = threading.Thread(target=self.buffer) t1 = threading.Thread(target=Network(self.handle).CSQ()) t.start() t1.start()` i put this inside run. nothing output.

Comment: If you do so, you are not using the `threading.Thread` object anymore, so you have to do that instead of `device.start()`. Edit: what I mean is that your class doesn't have to inherit from `threading.Thread`.